# Trouble aligning/calibrating camera with laser scanner

Tags: cameras, calibration, opencv, laser, point-cloud

I have a robot which has 2 multi-spectral cameras and 1 laser scanner attached. In the end I would like to have the images from the cameras aligned with the scanner so that I can have spectral information added to the scanner's point cloud. However I am having some troubles with the final alignment and am struggling to find a way to identify the location of the error. I was thus wondering if any of you know of any datasets or online exercises that deal with this problem where the correct outputs are given? ION this way I could test my approach on the dataset and see where my errors stem from.

Comment: Hi there! Is it a calibration problem that you're having? If that's the case did you have a look at method for extrinsic parameter calibration?

Answer (score 2):

Within ros there is a [lidar_camera_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/lidar_camera_calibration) package that should take care of this for you! Their github page has a detailed readme. If you aren't using ros, you can probably take a look at the core functions and compare it with your work.

Autoware foundation has also released their own [autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator](https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/sensing/autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator.html) package which is more recent.